# VBA Script Issues - Find Function Returning Error

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2017, vba

**Disclaimer:** Ok so first things first - I am new to VB scripting, so testing and compiling is something of a learning curve at the moment..

**My Goal:** Please correct me anywhere I am wrong here - I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017 to edit and test my VB script, and I need it to do the following:

1. Run on a given folder looking for any Excel .xlsx files
2. Find the cell with value "Date" on a worksheet named "Setup" in each file

   - If it's not there, skip the file
   - If it is - update the cell to the right of it to today's date
3. Refresh all connections in the file, save it and go on to the next one
4. Repeat until all are done

So far, it does open all files in a given folder, refreshes connections, saves and closes - but I need it to do **Step 2** above.. Don't mind the commented out parts that are working.

**Current State**

First attempt looks like below (although incomplete) - now getting an error when building the solution saying I need to "declare" xlValues, xlWhole and xlByRows which should be all part of the Find function as parameters anyway ??

```
Module RefreshAll_Folder
Sub Main()
                Dim ConnectivityPath, RefreshDate, fso, xl, EOMloop, SetupPage, wb
                Dim sval As Range

                '--- Set variables ---
                SetupPage = "Setup"
                RefreshDate = Now
                ConnectivityPath= "<networkpath>\Connectivity"

                fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                EOMloop = fso.GetFolder(ConnectivityPath).Files


                '--- FOR CONNECTIVITY ---

                xl.Visible = True

                For Each f In EOMloop
                    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "xlsx" Then
                        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
                        wb = wb.Sheets(SetupPage).Range("A1:F7")

                        sval = wb.Find(What:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues,
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,
                                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                        wb.select(sval)

                        ' wb.Worksheets("Setup").Range("B2").Value = Now
                        '    wb.RefreshAll

                        wb.Save
                        wb.Close
                    End If
                Next

                xl.Quit
            End Sub
End Module
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What language is this really?  Are you maybe writing VB.NET here?  Your issue is that you're using late binding and so without a reference to the Excel object library your code has no way to know what you mean by `xlValues` etc.  Those are built-in constants in Excel and you've not told your code where to look for them.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams - yes, you're right, figured that would be the case!
I am trying to develop it to VBA syntax as I want it to eventually be a .vbs script that our analysts can run for excel sheets.. What changes do I need to make? 

Hate to be a pain!

Comment: You also need `Set sval = ` as it's an object, then just `sval.select` (not that there's any need to select it shown)

Comment: You would be much better off just writing it as vbscript if that's what you want (and BTW that's not the same as VBA *or* VB.NET)